# Circular NSSlider keeps wrapping

Tags: objective-c, macos

I 'm using the circular `NSSlider` on OS X (the one that looks like a volume control) with Interface Builder.

How do I prevent the NSSlider value from wrapping back to zero as I rotate the knob?

I just want it to keep increasing endlessly as I turn it clock wise, and continuously decrease endlessly as I turn it counter clockwise, but it keeps wrapping back to zero ex.  0 1 2 3    0 1 2 3   0 1 2 3

Anybody knows how to solve it?

Comment: You have to detect if it crosses the 0 threshold and keep a variable tracking your current value in a variable somewhere.

Comment: To build on @nielsbot's answer, as in a subclass of NSSlider.

Answer (score 1):

Nielsbot has it right. 
You won't get this functionality without subclassing (or an ugly category)

NSSlider is designed to have upper and lower bounds.

You can take advantage of it in a simple subclass by tracking something like "number of laps around the track" and compensate your actual value. Do the reverse when loading the last value used.